# Swift Progress View Value Passed Around Functions

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am needing to implement a progress bar that takes into account a couple of factors.

I have three different classes, my ViewController, a Networking class to handle the network calls and a dataManager class to handle all the db operations.

Now my progressView lives in my viewcontroller and I am looking at a way of updating it as each of the different operations are performed in the other classes.

I am using Alamofire so I know I can use .progress{} to catch the value of the JSON progress but that would also mean exposing the ViewController to the Networking class, which I assume is bad practice?

I think this should be achieved using completion handlers but as I have already setup another thread for handling the JSON / DB operation I'm not wanting to over complicate it anymore than I need to

**Networking**:

```
 func makeGetRequest(url : String, params : [String : String]?, completionHandler: (responseObject: JSON?, error: NSError?) -> ())  -> Request? {

        return Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: params, encoding: .URL)
            .progress { _, _, _ in
                           //bad practice?
                progressView.setProgress(request.progress.fractionCompleted, animated: true)
            }
            .responseJSON { request, response, data, error in completionHandler(
                responseObject:
                {


                  let json = JSON(data!)

                    if let anError = error
                    {

                        println(error)
                    }
                    else if let data: AnyObject = data
                    {

                        let json = JSON(data)
                                          }


                    return json

                    }(),
                error: error

                )
        }
    }
```

**ViewController**:

```
 dataManager.loadData({(finished: Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in


            if let errorMessage = error{
                 self.syncProgress.setProgress(0, animated: true)

                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Network Error", message:
                    errorMessage.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))
                 self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
            if finished{
                for i in 0..<100 {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {
                        sleep(1)
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            self.counter++
                            return
                        })
                    })
                }

            }






        })
```

As you can see I am waiting on the finished boolean in the datamanger class to be set before updating the progress bar. The thing is, dataManager makes a call to networking and performs a bunch of other stuff before it finishes, it would be handy to update the progress bar along the way but I'm not sure of the best approach?

**DataManager**:

```
 func loadData(completion: (finished: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void) {

        var jsonError: NSError?

        networking.makeGetRequest(jobsUrl, params: nil) { json, networkError  in

//....

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with swift so I can't give you a code example but the way I would do this is create a protocol on your Networking class `NetworkingDelegate` and implement that protocol in your ViewController. The protocol method would be something like (in objective-c) `NetworkingRequestDidUpdatProgress:(float progress)`

This is assuming your ViewController calls Networking.makeGetRequest. If it's another class, you would implement the delegate in that class, or you could bubble up the delegate calls to your ViewController through the DataManager class.

Comment: thats the problem, kind of, my view controller makes a call to datamanager which calls networking. Would the AppDelegate be a suitable place to put the delegate function then?

Comment: No, try not to do anything in your AppDelegate. You could make a delegate for Networking and for DataManager. Then DataManager would be Networking's delegate, and ViewController would be DataManager's delegate, which would require you to bubble up the delegate calls. Or, you could use NSNotificationCenter and just send a notification when the progress is updated, and include the request or some unique ID with the notification that lets the listener know which request the notification is about

Comment: NSNotificationCenter is an interesting approach, I assume I don't have to worry about separate threads too much with UIProgressView??

Comment: well just make sure you send the notification on the main thread and you should be fine. Any updates to UIProgressView have to happen on the main thread.